# Scaffolding Razor Pages server-side CRUD codes with WebAPI as data source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, razor-pages

Razor Pages have scaffolding tools that use EF data context or source. Can there be a version that uses WebAPI as data source? Or an HttpClient service implementation?

Comment: No there isn't. The only scaffolding currently available depends on an EF DbContext.

Comment: There's scaffolding that works with EF, because 1) EF is a known quantity and 2) EF has abstractions that can be used to satisfy the inherently generic nature of a scaffold. Each and every API will be different, so there's no way to generically work with any given API. As such, it's impossible to build a scaffold for that.

Comment: I was hoping at least something that is based on the VS scaffolded WebAPI output (with EF CRUD). In a sense, if the existing template can be extended to also generate the boilerplate code that consumes the WebAPI in a Razor page either client-side (JavaScript) or server-side (HttpClient) as options.